# rjxs filter() don't seem to work on angular 9

Tags: typescript, angular9

products.json:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "imagem": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505740420928-5e560c06d30e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEzOTExNH0",
    "rating": 3,
    "title": "Product 1",
    "slug": "product-1",
    "description": "Dolor ullamco incididunt sit do deserunt proident anim cillum sunt consequat quis amet qui nostrud. Commodo et consequat sint ullamco ea sunt commodo sunt culpa aute. Incididunt eiusmod aute aute aliquip voluptate voluptate labore consequat commodo voluptate. Proident mollit nisi quis in nisi occaecat amet incididunt labore adipisicing exercitation enim qui est. Dolore esse ad do sint non. Ea ad dolor consectetur ex veniam.",
    "price": "55.63",
    "stock": 44
},...]
```

products service:

```
show(slug: string) : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('/assets/products.json').pipe(filter((product: Product) => product.slug == slug );
}
```

when I make this call no data comes:

```
this.productService.show('product-1').subscribe((product: Product) => {
     console.log(product); // nothing
});
```

when I use map() to debug:

```
show(slug: string) : Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get('/assets/products.json').pipe(map((product: Product) => console.log(product))); 
     // Log: (23) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
}
```

does anyone know why it doesn't work with filter()?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the filter operator. The filter operator will not iterate over each item in the emitted product array in your show method. What you are currently doing is [{},{}] === foo.bar. It will never be truthy. You need to use map instead the filter on that mapped array value. filter RxJS operator does not iterate through the array for you, you need to map or similar to execute Array.prototype.filter on that array. If your stream emitted for each item in the array, it would be different.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky you're right, i got from here https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter, but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Alexander Staroselsky mentioned in the comment, you need to first map it and then call filter, as http.get returns an Observable, you can't call directly filter on it.

```
show(slug: string) : Observable<Product[]> {
    this.http.get<Product[]>('/assets/products.json').pipe(map(products => products.filter(product => product.slug == slug )))
}
```

Comment: You need to update your answer. You are executing map directly against the Observable. Change map to pipe. `pipe(map(products => products.filter(foo => whatever)))`

Comment: And the types are wrong. `Product` should be `Product[]` and the code should not need it, the type annotation on the callback is acting as a hidden type assertion on a parameter of type `any`. It should look like `this.http.get<Product[]>('/assets/products.json').pipe(map(products => products.filter(product => whatever)))`. Also, you don't know that Product is a class, and hopefully it is not.

Comment: sorry guys, looks like i messed up

Comment: return type should be `Observable<Product[]>` or we can omit it and let type inference handle it, which it will, correctly inferring `Observable<Product[]>`